# Copy files based on path from file

Tags: python, subprocess

My script does the following:

```
./myscript pathfile.txt
```

- Mounting image file containing a filesystem to /mnt/filesystem/.

When browsing the paths look like this:

```
/mnt/filesystem/Windows/somefile.exe
/mnt/filesystem/Program Files/somefile.exe
```

- Searches pathfile.txt and extracts all paths from the file.

Extracted paths looks like this:

```
C:\windows\somefile.exe
C:\program Files\somefile.exe
```

- Then im trying to convert the path from pathfile.txt to fit my systempath so i can copy out the .exe files from the `/mnt/filesystem/`.
- Removing 3 first chars from line, removing the C:.
- Using replace on the \, setting it to /.
- Adding mount destination.

Now the path looks like this:

```
/mnt/filesystem/windows/somefile.exe
/mnt/filesystem/program files/somefile.exe
```

Im trying to copy the files using the path names but it wont work because of spacing in paths, upper/lower case etc.

So my problem:

How do i dynamically adapt to path differences when it comes to upper/lower case, spacing etc?

Im now trying to copy `/mnt/filesystem/program files/somefile.exe` which really is at `/mnt/filesystem/"Program Files"/somefile.exe`, using `subprocess.call`.

I'm really new to programming so please give me really easy examples. thank you

UPDATE:

I made a smaller script out of my big script and made something i could understand based on your input Sebastian, and now i have the code below. However, the code is not working it seems.  The script is running but no files are being copied.

```
Argument = pathfile.txt

fileName = sys.argv[1]
inputFile = open(fileName, "r")
paths = inputFile.read()

src_dir = "/mnt/filesystem/"
dest_dir = "/home/user/copyhere/"

for path in re.finditer('(c(?i):\\\.*?\.exe)', paths):
  hits = path.groups()
for line in hits:
  line = line.replace("\\", "/").lower()
  line = ntpath.splitdrive(line)[1].lstrip("\\/")
  assert src_dir.endswith(os.path.sep)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
   for filename in files:
     path = os.path.join(root, filename)
    normalized_path = path[len(src_dir):].lower()
    if normalized_path in paths:
      shutil.copy(path, dest_dir)
      paths.remove(normalized_path)
      if not paths:
        sys.exit()

#As mentioned the pathfile.txt is not neat and tidy, its a real mess, therefore im using regex to extract the paths.
#BELOW ARE HOW THE OUTPUT LOOKS LIKE:
#Real path:/mnt/filesystem/Program Files/ESET/ESET NOD32 Antivirus/somefile.exe
#Script path: /mnt/filesystem/program files/eset/eset nod32 antivirus/somefile.exe
#Real path: /mnt/filesystem/Program Files/Elantech/somefile.exe
#Script path: /mnt/filesystem/program files/elantech/somefile.exe
#Real path: /mnt/filesystem/Program Files (x86)/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static/somefile.exe
#Script path: /mnt/filesystem/program files (x86)/ati technologies/ati.ace/core-static/somefile.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for removing that unworthy answer (whoever, I forgot to memorize the user name), but this way this question stays unanswered and thus draws more attention than a question which is marked as answered but whose answer isn't helpful at all.

Comment: I think you mean that you have Ⓐ a file system you mount and Ⓑ a text file in which paths are listed which are in this file system.  Is that correct?  Then if you mount that file system in a Unix system you should have the paths below the mount point as they are in the text file.  The _only_ differences should be the prepended `C:` and the backslashes ``\`` which will be slashes `/`.  Spaces and upper/lower characters should stay untouched.  Can you confirm that in your situation?

Comment: Indention is significant in Python. The code in your question produces `IndentationError`.

Comment: The indent is just because of me copying the script.  Indent is correct in my py script so dont worry about it.  Yes, the paths are correct and the C:\ is removed and slashes are switched, but my problem is I'm using a windows program to generate the pathfile (not possible on linux with my tools), so the paths are different in windwos than in linux when it comes to upper/lowercase.

Comment: As you see in the comment part of my script the paths are almost correct. Is there a way i can use the os module mentioned by StephenH to "regex" my way to the correct path, if you know what i mean.  Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: @user3323307: do you understand what is the purpose of `.lower()` calls in [my code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21919241/4279)?

Comment: Actually, user3323307, @J.F.Sebastian's suggestion is much more complete than mine, my answer does not really address your issue as much as I thought it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy original case-insensitive Windows paths on a system which has case-sensitive file system, you can rely that Windows disallows the user to create a second file differing only in case that allows to compare paths using normalized case to create a mapping:

```
"path from pathfile.txt" -> "mounted path on case-sensitive filesystem"
```

You could use `ntpath` module even on Unix to manipulate Windows paths e.g.:

```
>>> import ntpath
>>> ntpath.splitdrive('C:\windows\somefile.exe')
('C:', '\\windows\\somefile.exe')
>>> ntpath.normcase('C:\program Files/somefile.exe')
'c:\\program files\\somefile.exe'
```

There shouldn't be any issues with spaces in paths if you use `subprocess.call()` correctly. Though you don't need `subprocess.call()` to copy a file; you could use `shutil.copy()` instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ntpath
import os
import shutil
import sys

def normalize(path):
    path = path.strip()
    path = ntpath.splitdrive(path)[1].lstrip("\\/") # remove C:\ or C:/
    return path.replace("\\", "/").lower()

# get non-blank lines and normalize paths
with open(sys.argv[1]) as pathfile:
    paths = set(filter(bool, map(normalize, pathfile)))

# find the paths in the source directory tree & copy them to the destination 
src_dir = "/mnt/filesystem/"        # where to copy from
assert src_dir.endswith(os.path.sep) # needed for `path[len(src_dir):]` below
dest_dir = "/destination/directory" # where to copy to
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir): # traverse directory tree
    for filename in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        normalized_path = path[len(src_dir):].lower()
        if normalized_path in paths: # path is from pathfile.txt
           shutil.copy(path, dest_dir) # copy
           paths.remove(normalized_path)
           if not paths: # no more paths to copy
              sys.exit()
```

<sub>(not tested)</sub>

Comment: Looking at the output of this i can't really see that it does anything different then what i already have.  The path looks good, but still it wont find my files based on correct path because the real path is using upper or lowercase in the directory name.

Comment: @user3323307: add to the code `print(paths)` and `print(normalized_path)` and post the results. The comparison is case-insensitive -- it is the purpose of `.lower()` calls in two places: 1. convert all paths from `pathfile` to lowercase 2. convert paths from `src_dir` to lowercase before searching for them in `paths` set. My guess, you've incorrectly parsed paths from `pathfile`. If it is the case then 1. write script that does nothing but write one path per line in pathfile_good 2. give this file to my  script.

Comment: Running your original script with pathfile looking like this:

C:\program files\eset\eset nod32 antivirus\egui.exe
C:\program files\elantech\etdctrl.exe

Result of paths was:
set(['program files/elantech/etdctrl.exe\n', etc.

Result of path was (correct!):
/mnt/filesystem/Program Files/ESET/ESET NOD32 Antivirus/egui.exe etc.

Result of normalized_path was: 
program files/common files/ati technologies/multimedia/amdh264enc32.dll etc.

I just dont know whats wrong. The /mnt/filesystem/ is read only, but i guess the changes are only in memory.

Comment: @user3323307: I forgot to strip leading/trailing whitespace. Newlines in particular. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually getting those paths and trying to determine how to handle upper/lower case items, I would recommend using the built in `os` module in python. This way the operating system is actually telling you the locations. Here is an example for getting the current working directory, the Program Files directory, and the related absolute and relative references for them.

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.getcwd()
C:\Users\sheindel
>>> print os.environ["ProgramFiles"]
C:\Program Files
>>> print os.path.abspath(os.environ["ProgramFiles"])
C:\Program Files
>>> print os.path.relpath(os.environ["ProgramFiles"])
..\..\Program Files
```

Just keep in mind that you will have two different program directories if it is a 64-bit machine. The above example will get the Program Files directory on a 32-bit system and it will get the 64-bit Program Files directory on a 64-bit system. If on a 64 bit system, the following code will get the 32-bit Program Files

```
>>> print os.getcwd()
C:\Users\sheindel
>>> print os.environ["ProgramFiles(x86)"]
C:\Program Files (x86)
>>> print os.path.relpath(os.environ["ProgramFiles(x86)"])
..\..\Program Files (x86)
>>> print os.path.abspath(os.environ["ProgramFiles(x86)"])
C:\Program Files (x86)
```

Take some time to read up on the [python docs on the os module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) and the [python docs on the os.path module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) specifically on os.path

Comment: Thanks for the input StephenH.  Im not quite sure how to use this together with the input file. Do you have an example?  See my update.